# problems with Recursion - C++

Tags: c++, recursion

Given a natural number n (1 <= n <= 500000), please output the summation of all its proper divisors.

Definition: A proper divisor of a natural number is the divisor that is strictly less than the number.

e.g. number 20 has 5 proper divisors: 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, and the divisor summation is: 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 10 = 22.
<<--This is a challenge i am trying to do and i am using recursion

```
int find_sum(std::vector <int> nums,long int sum,int num_now,long int j)
{

if(j<nums[num_now])
{
    if(nums[num_now]%j==0)
    {
        sum=sum+j;
    }
    return find_sum(nums,sum,num_now,j+1);
}
else
{
 return sum;
}

}
```

sum is the sum of all divisors,nums is the vector i stored number in,num_now is current member in vector,int j is 1 i use it to search for dividers,sadly using this i cant use numbers like 500000 it give's me error,is there any better way to do it or have i made a mistake somewhere.

--Thank you for your time

Comment: Does it have to be made using recursion?

Comment: Any reason that you want to use recursion?

Comment: Before considering optimizations, did you try a brute force solution just to make it work?

Comment: Be aware of *Stack Overflows*, where your program runs out of memory due to the depth or recursion.  You can better control the iterations using a loop instead.

Comment: are you aware that there is a straightforward [formula](http://planetmath.org/formulaforsumofdivisors) to calculate this quantity? No need to use recursion...

Comment: I understand that i do not need to use recursion but i wish to use it for educational means

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **recursive** way to solve your problem:

```
int find_sum(int x, int i)
{
  if(i == 0)
    return 0;
  if(x % i == 0)
    return i + find_sum(x, (i-1));
  return find_sum(x, (i-1));
}
```

You need to call `find_sum(N, N-1);` in order to find sum of dividers of N (`i` must be less than given `N` because of strict inequality).

In your case it would be `find_sum(20, 19);`

e.g. my function returns:

- `71086` for `N = 50000`
- `22` for `N = 20`
- `0` for `N = 1`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the reason why you need to use recursion for solving this problem. I would prefer a more staightforward way to solve it.

```
long CalculateSumOfDivisors(int number)
{
    long sum = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<number; i++)
    {
        // If the remainder of num/i is zero
        // then i divides num. So we add it to the 
        // current sum. 
        if(number%i==0)
        {
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Furthermore, we could write a more optimal algorithm, if we note the following:

*Let that we have a number n and d is the smallest divisor of n that is greater of 1. (Apparently if the number n is a prime number there is any such a divisor). Then the larget divisor of n is the number n/d.*

Based on this we can formulate a more optimal algorithm.

```
long CalculateSumOfDivisors(int number)
{
    int smallestDivisor = FindSmallestDivisor(number);
    if(smallestDivisor==1) return 1;

    long sum = smallestDivisor;

    // Calculate the possible greatest divisor.
    int possibleGreatestDivisor = (int)floor(number/smallestDivisor); 

    for(int i=smallestDivisor+1; i<=possibleGreatestDivisor; i++)
    {
        if(number%i==0)
        {
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int FindSmallestDivisor(int number)
{
    int smallestDivisor = 1;
    for(int i=2; i<number; i++)
    {
        if(number%i==0)
        {
            smallestDivisor = i;
            break;     
        } 
    }
    return smallestDivisor;
}
```

Comment: You can also stop at `number/2`.   No value greater than 1/2 can be a divisor, right?

Comment: This is correct ! But if the smallest divisor is 3 then we can stop at `number/3`, which I think is a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use recursion.

Instead start by looping from 1..N-1

When you find a divisor adjust the end value for the loop. Example if 2 is a divisor then you know N/2 is also a divisor. And just as important you know there can be no further divisors in the range ]N/2:N[. Likewise if 3 is a divisor then you know N/3 is also a divisor and you know there are no more divisors in the range ]N/3:N[.

Following that concept you can reduced the number of loops significantly for most numbers.

Something like:

```
long find_sum(int num)
{
    long sum = 0;
    int max = num;
    int i = 1;
    while(i < max)
    {
        if(num % i == 0)
        {
            sum += i;        // Add i to the sum
            max = num / i;   // Decrement max for performance
            if (max != i && max != num)
            {
                sum += max;  // Add max when max isn't equal i
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Example:

```
num = 10
sum = 0
i = 1 -> sum = 1, max = 10
i = 2 -> sum = 1+2+5, max = 5
i = 3 -> sum = 1+2+5, max = 5
i = 4 -> sum = 1+2+5, max = 5
i = 5 -> return 8 (1+2+5)

num = 64
sum = 0
i = 1 -> sum = 1, max = 64
i = 2 -> sum = 1+2+32, max = 32
i = 3 -> sum = 1+2+32, max = 32
i = 4 -> sum = 1+2+32+4+16, max = 16
i = 5 -> sum = 1+2+32+4+16, max = 16
i = 6 -> sum = 1+2+32+4+16, max = 16
i = 7 -> sum = 1+2+32+4+16, max = 16
i = 8 -> sum = 1+2+32+4+16+8, max = 8
i = 9 -> return (1+2+32+4+16+8)
```

The number of loops are kept down by changing `max` whenever a new divisor is found.

Answer (score 0):

I tried writing code with main function asking user to give the it wants to get sum of. here is the code , hope it helps.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int Sum(int min, int max, int &val, int &sum){
if(min >= max)
    return 0;

for ( ; min < max; min++){
    if ( val%min == 0){
        sum += min + val/min;
        return Sum(++min,val/min, val,sum);
    }
}
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int s=1;
    int val;
    cout <<"Enter Val to sum:";
    cin >> val;
    Sum(2,val,val,s);
    cout <<"Sum is :"<<s<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here Sum function is used recursively and passed parameters as shown in the code.

Hope it helps.